# Do I need any Oracle services installed on a client running Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to a remote Oracle database using Oracle SQL Developer from a Win8.1 machine. When I try to connect to the remote database, I get this commonly reported error:

"IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection - Vendor code 17002"

I have the ports 1521 and 1522 (both TCP/UDP) set to open in my router. These are the ports used by the external database.

All Google results for this issue assume that you are trying to connect to a local Oracle database, with the solution being to open the ports on your router and to enable all Oracle services. The database I am trying to connect to is remote. The credentials I am using work fine when running Oracle SQL Developer within my University network. The Oracle db is not hosted on the University network. With all that in mind, do I need any Oracle services running on my client PC when trying to connect to a remote Oracle database using Oracle SQL Developer? IF so, which ones do I need and where can I obtain them? There are currently no Oracle services running on my client PC.

Comment: Are you e.g. at home and trying to connect to an oracle db hosted inside your university's firewall, on their network somewhere? What is the usual way you access on-network resources when you're off-network? VPN? Have them open their firewall for you? Etc..

Comment: The Oracle db is not within the University network. It is hosted by Oracle themselves.

Comment: *"The Oracle db ... is hosted by Oracle themselves. "* You need to explain that a bit more. Are you trying to connect to the Oracle cloud?

Comment: I don't know. I have access to a DB System Instance that I am able to connect to using Oracle SQL Developer with a username, password, hostname, port, and sid (Basic connection type).

Comment: You may need to ask the university how/ whether you can do this.  It is entirely possible that they've configured their cloud subscription to allow connections only from machines on the university network, for example.  It would be rather dangerous to configure a database to allow connections from random machines anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need is the software on your machine, and a network that can reach the database via the listener service and its port (often 1521)

Included with SQL Developer is an Oracle JDBC driver...that's all we need to connect to an Oracle Database, assuming you have a Oracle JDK on the machine so the software itself can run.

If you're off the university network, you'll need a VPN or SSH Tunnel to get to your database and maybe even some network admin's assistance.

If you want to work on your project at home, put a database on your laptop.

Comment: The answer is the same..you need to be able to reach it, whatever Network it's on.

Comment: @leoton but if the uni own the dB you want to use eg perhaps they subscribe to a device from oracle, and you can connect to it while on-net then you’ll need to use a VPN to make your off-net connection into an on-net one. That’s what a vpn does; turns your “not at work” internet connection into an “at work” one, virtually/conceptually placing you inside the network you connect into

Answer (score 0):

1) No, you wont need any Oracle Services installed on your local PC/Laptop.

2)This is a firewall issue. Either you need a VPN or network is a private n/w. Check up with that local IT of your department to understand the db configuration.